# Unwanted space above MapView in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, dictionary, swiftui, space

The problem is illustrated by the following snippet. There should be no space between the green background Text and the MapView, still there is, see picture. How can I get rid of it ?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            Text("Hello, World!").background(Color.gray)
            Text("the classic").background(Color.green)
            MapView().frame(height: 300)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: did you try `VStack(spacing: 0)`

Comment: it works. thank you! But i am a bit puzzled, why there is no extra space between the Text views then?